# Django get data from Partition in Model

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

We are building a website and our system is dynamically partitioned with the architect plugin. Is there any way to look into the partitioned table directly and get data from it with Django Models?

Can we pass the table name while filtering or retrieving the data, can I do so?

Comment: There's no nice way that I know of built-in with Django, as a last resort you could always use `Model.objects.raw()`

Comment: You can use proxy models. Please check out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)